# Jquery dialog box stays up the the 2nd time I use it on a page

Tags: ajax, jquery

I've got a dialog box that the user selects items from.  The first time it is used, it works perfectly.  After that it stays visible after the user submits its form.  Are there any common reasons why this might happen?

Here's the code for the box:

```
<head>
    <script>  
    $(function() {    
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();  
        $( "#Add").click(function(){
             $( "#dialog" ).dialog("close"); 
        });
    });  
</script>
</head>
    <body> <div id="dialog" title="Select Item">
        Position <%= @i %><br /><br />   
       <%= form_tag( {:controller => :foos, :action => :update, :position => @i , :id => @foo.id }, :remote => true) do %>
            <td>
                <%= select_tag :name, options_for_select(@list) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'position', @i %>
                <%= submit_tag "Add" ,:id=> "Add", :class => "btn" %>

            </td>
        <% end %>
       </div>  
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are going to have multiple elements that have `Add` as their ID. That is likely the problem.

You could use the `btn` class instead to attach your click listener. This should resolve the issue:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog("close"); 
});
```

Comment: If you mean `<%= submit_tag "Add" ,:id=> "Add", :class => "btn" %>`, that's just the notatation to put text on the button.

Comment: @JoeEssey what does `:id => "Add"` statement do? I'm not sure what server-side technology you're using, but that looks like it's setting the ID of a submit button.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thanks for the additional info.  You're correct that each time the button is activated, it will be called "Add" because of `:id => "Add"`.  I think I can work this from here.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeEssey Great; glad my answer was helpful to you. Since this answer helped resolve your question, would you mind accepting it? Thanks and good luck!

Comment: does your code mean that all elements in dialogue boxes with the class of .btn will call that method?  It's not working as is and I don't know what to change.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeEssey Yep, it means that any element tagged with a `btn` class will close the dialog on the `click` event. Your code has some other issues, for example you have `td` elements that aren't part of a `table`. You might want to try to narrow down what's not working and post any error messages to a new question on stackoverflow.